# Java runs one thread at a time when it should be running them altogether

Tags: java, multithreading

The following code multiplies a list of matrices. There is a function that breaks the list into two lists, and calculates each list's output matrix in a new thread, recursively. If the function reaches a list including only one matrix, it returns the matrix, else it takes the two output matrices of the two aforementioned lists (lets say the first matrix has k rows), and it creates k threads, each calculating one row of the output.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Q3_thread
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // input
        // Note: input matrices are presumed correct and in order
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();
        Matrix[] matrices = new Matrix[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < matrices.length; i++)
        {
            String string = scanner.nextLine().trim();
            String[] dimensions = string.split("\\*");
            int m = Integer.valueOf(dimensions[0]), n = Integer.valueOf(dimensions[1]);
            matrices[i] = new Matrix(m, n);
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
                {
                    matrices[i].a[j][k] = scanner.nextInt();
                }
                scanner.nextLine();
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
        // log
//      System.out.println('---');
//      for (int i = 0; i < matrices.length; i++)
//      {
//          System.out.print(matrices[i]);
//      }

        // output
        MatricesRunnable mainRunnable = new MatricesRunnable(matrices, 0, matrices.length);
        Thread mainThread = new Thread(mainRunnable);
        mainThread.start();
        try
        {
            mainThread.join();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.print(mainRunnable.output);
    }
}

class Matrix
{
    public int m, n;
    public int[][] a;

    public Matrix(int m, int n)
    {
        this.m = m;
        this.n = n;
        this.a = new int[m][n];
    }

    public static Matrix multiply(Matrix left, Matrix right)
    {
        Matrix output = new Matrix(left.m, right.n);
        RowRunnable[] rowRunnables = new RowRunnable[left.m];
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[left.m];
        for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
        {
            rowRunnables[i] = new RowRunnable(left, right, i);
            threads[i] = new Thread(rowRunnables[i]);
            threads[i].start();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                threads[i].join();
                output.a[i] = rowRunnables[i].output;
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            }
        }
        return output;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        String output = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < this.m; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < this.n; j++)
            {
                output += this.a[i][j] + " ";
            }
            output += "\n";
        }
        return output;
    }
}

class MatricesRunnable implements Runnable
{
    public Matrix[] matrices;
    public int startIndex, endIndex;  // [,)
    public Matrix output;

    public MatricesRunnable(Matrix[] matrices, int startIndex, int endIndex)
    {
        this.matrices = matrices;
        this.startIndex = startIndex;
        this.endIndex = endIndex;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        if (this.endIndex - this.startIndex == 0)
        {
            output = null;
        }
        else if (this.endIndex - this.startIndex == 1)
        {
            output = matrices[this.startIndex];
        }
        else if (this.endIndex - this.startIndex == 2)
        {
            output = Matrix.multiply(matrices[this.startIndex], matrices[this.startIndex + 1]);
        }
        else
        {
            int halfIndex = (endIndex + startIndex) / 2;  // int division
            if ((this.endIndex - this.startIndex) % 2 == 1)  // so that the longer sublist is at left
            {
                halfIndex++;
            }
            MatricesRunnable leftMatrixRunnable = new MatricesRunnable(matrices, startIndex, halfIndex);
            Thread leftMatrixThread = new Thread(leftMatrixRunnable);
            leftMatrixThread.start();
            MatricesRunnable rightMatrixRunnable = new MatricesRunnable(matrices, halfIndex, endIndex);
            Thread rightMatrixThread = new Thread(rightMatrixRunnable);
            rightMatrixThread.start();
            try
            {
                leftMatrixThread.join();
                rightMatrixThread.join();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            output = Matrix.multiply(leftMatrixRunnable.output, rightMatrixRunnable.output);
        }
    }
}

class RowRunnable implements Runnable
{
    public Matrix left, right;
    public int index;  // which row
    public int[] output; // index-th row of output

    public RowRunnable(Matrix left, Matrix right, int index)
    {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
        this.index = index;
        this.output = new int[this.right.n];
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.right.n; i++)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < this.left.n; j++)
            {
                sum += left.a[index][j] * right.a[j][i];
            }
            this.output[i] = sum; 
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, this code should be running several threads simultaneously, but when I check the threads (using htop command) there is only one running thread, and as a result it takes the same amount of time to produce the result as when I don't use threads at all. Why is that the case?

You can use the following code to generate testcases:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    srand(atoi(argv[1]));
    int n = atoi(argv[2]);
    int maxRC = atoi(argv[3]);
    int maxNum = atoi(argv[4]);
    cout << n << endl;
    int r = rand() % maxRC + 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
    int c = rand() % maxRC + 1;
    cout << r << '*' << c << endl;
    for(int j = 0; j < r; j++)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < c; k++)
        {
            cout << rand() % (maxNum + 1) << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    r = c;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The arguments are respectively: random seed, number of matrices, maximum length of rows and columns, maximum of the numbers in the matrices

Comment: because you have just one thread, and it is mainThread, you must create multiple threads.

Comment: Do you actually see multiple existing threads alive and only one running, or do the threads not spawn at all?

Comment: @Ali Amiri Yes, but the mainThread creates two thread and each of those create two more,... please read the question more carefully.

Comment: @chrylis Multiple threads (constantly 13) and only one running.

Comment: Can you maybe provide the input that you use?

Comment: First, I'd add logging statements so that you can actually trace the order of thread starts and completions. Also keep in mind that there's nothing in Java or operating systems generally that says that threads *have* to be run in parallel.

Comment: @Ian2thedv The input is a 5MB text file

Comment: You should design this with worker threads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572145/worker-thread-in-java. The algorithm to split up the work is best done as a prep work and then feed workers with jobs to perform.

Comment: @KeAn These *are* worker threads. An executor might be better, but that's a different matter entirely.

Comment: @chrylis Not really the pattern of workers since it is threads created inside threads created inside threads. Split up the matrix in the main thread and then feed it to a pool of threads that takes the input and calls Matrix.multiply(). Perhaps a bad choice of word to call it "workers" instead of executor.

Comment: @KeAn I can't do that, it has to be calculated in this tree structure. I can't change the algorithm.

Comment: Do you have any idea how long your `RowRunnable` takes? I suspect that the execution time per may simply be so short you're not seeing the threads in action. In this case, your model is probably more harm than help, since threads are moderately expensive to create, and you're constantly creating and destroying them.

Comment: @chrylis if the matrices are large enough (say 10000 * 10000) RowRunnable takes a relatively long time, but I still see just one thread running. You can generate such a testcase and see for yourself. I understand that the overhead can be a lot, but that still doesn't explain the behavior I see.

Comment: `and as a result it takes the same amount of time to produce the result as when I don't use threads at all. Why is that the case?` If you start more threads than the your CPU can support you may lose gain.  Take a look at the ForkJoinPool and try to solve it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You are *[joining](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html)* the other threads which in fact behaves like a sequential order of work.

Calling the `join` method on another thread causes the current (calling) thread to actually pause and wait for the other thread until it has finished its work. In fact that lets you see only one thread working at a single point of time, although chances are that this will always be another thread when look at different times.

---

An edit as an anser to the comments:

One might think that calling `thread.start()` actually starts a thread, but this is not the case. It is a simple hint to the JVM that a new thread now can be started.

The time between creating all those threads, calling the `start` method on them, then joining them, is so little that you will not see two threads running simultaneously.

Comment: Yeah, but he's spinning off all of the threads before going back to join them.

Comment: That is true, but I call join() after creating both child threads, so all threads at the last level (calculating rows) should be running simultaneously.

Comment: @chrylis But the time between starting those threads and then joining them is so short that it will look like a single action. It's simply too fast.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose join() waits for the thread to finish, so I don't understand what you mean by "Time between". please refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html

Comment: Incorrect on the facts. `thread.start()` [**starts the thread**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()). To what extent the new thread is independently scheduled is up to the OS, and partly to the JVM, but from the standpoint of the JMM, it's running. In fact, if the JVM *didn't* start the thread, an immediate join would be a deadlock.